# Keeping original request link between redirects in Django?

Tags: python, django, satchmo

I do use the default `django.core.context_processors.request` template context processor so I can access `request` instance of HttpRequest in my Django templates.

One use is to retrieve original sender url:

```
import re

nexturl_re = re.compile('\?next=(.+)$')

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_previous_url(context):
    try:
        return shop_base + \
            nexturl_re.search( context['request'].get_full_path() ).group(1)
    except (IndexError, AttributeError):
        return shop_base + '/'
```

I do use it to extract an  argument from sender url.

The issue is with some views that do http redirects to another views so the original optional parameter after `?next=` is lost.

Is there some way how to keep/pass the original url for specific views ?
For example following url dispatching of `smart.smart_add` view does a redirect. It does not accept optional keyword arguments.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns

urlpatterns += patterns('satchmo_store.shop.views',
    (r'^add/$', 'smart.smart_add', {}, 'satchmo_smart_add'),
```

Is there some other way than completely rewrite the original view function ?

Thanks.

**Update**
Based on *abstractpaper*'s answer solved the problem as follows:

1. Written a middleware class to pass around url arguments for redirect responses:

   ```
   import re

   nexturlopt_re = re.compile('(\?next=.+)$')

   class ForwardUrlArguments(object):
       def process_response(self, request, response):
           if response.status_code in (301, 302, …):
               new_location = response.get('Location')
               if new_location:
                   try:
                       new_location += nexturlopt_re.search(
                               request.get_full_path() ).group(1)
                   except (IndexError, AttributeError):
                       pass
               response['Location'] = new_location

           return response
   ```
2. In a views file decorate specific methods to apply middleware's response:

   ```
   from django.utils.decorators import decorator_from_middleware

   forward_urlargs = decorator_from_middleware(ForwardUrlArguments)

   @forward_urlargs
   def account_signin(request):
       …

   @forward_urlargs
   def cart_smart_add(request):
       …

   @forward_urlargs
   def cart_set_quantity(request):
       return cart.set_quantity(request)   # wrapped a library function
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) to catch HTTP 301 requests and pass on query parameters.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, however a bit heavyweight for a such specific case.

Comment: It's not gonna be heavy weight considering it will only execute for HTTP 301 requests. Sure, there is the if condition check but that's really really tiny.

Comment: When nobody else would add a more straightforward solution I'd make yours as accepted answer.

Comment: There is the [decorator_from_middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/utils/#django.utils.decorators.decorator_from_middleware) decorator which you can use to apply a middleware on view basis, however I'm not sure if you can utilize it for your use case as you need to apply it on a specific view to intercept the ongoing redirect call or the incoming HTTP 301 request.